# My computer can't find the git command

Tags: macos, git, python, path

I recently installed git on my computer (OSX 10.10.1) and when I run git I get `git: error: unable to find utility "git", not a developer tool or in PATH`. So I checked, found that I didn't have the directory that git was in in my `PATH` so I added it in. I checked and my `PATH` has it. My `PATH` is

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Users/Jesse/SDKs/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/Jesse/SDKs/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin`

You'll notice that the last one is `/usr/local/git/bin`. If I cd to /usr/local/git/bin and run `./git` then git runs just fine. I can't figure out what might be causing this. I tried restarting my computer too just in case without any change.

Comment: consider adding or symlinking to default bin  (aka /usr/bin)   that is using the version for android-sdk which presumably is not default called by OSX

Comment: That's interesting, there's already a git file in /usr/bin

Comment: What's your `sudo xcode-select -p` path?

Comment: Does agreeing to licence helps? `sudo xcodebuild -license`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make sure that you're working on the right XCode environment, for example:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Check the current value by: `sudo xcode-select -p`.

Then make sure you've accepted the license by running:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

and by typing `agree` and check if that works.

Double check if you're not overriding `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` system variable by unsetting it from your *rc* files. Test in Terminal by `echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

If none of above works, you've to change the order of your `PATH` by editing it in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` or by adding the following line:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: All of those tests are what you said they should be. Except I'm not sure what you mean by rc files

Comment: On terminal, type: `echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and see if you've any value. If it's empty, then it's fine as well.

Comment: it's empty unfortunately

Comment: @JesseGreen Then as workaround move your `/usr/local/git/bin` before `/usr/bin/` in your PATH in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`. If you don't have it, add `export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: moving `/usr/local/git/bin` to the beginning of my PATH seems to have solved the problem although I'm still very confused why it doesn't want to work normally but at least it's working now